# Modify Regex to convert uppercase to lowercase

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex

```
/**
 * For replacing illegal characters
 */
export const replacer = (el, filter) => {
  let elem = new d(el)
  let regex =
    'username' ? /[^a-z0-9_.@$#]/i : filter == 'bio' ? /[<>]/i : null

  elem.on('keyup', e => {
    let value = e.currentTarget.value
    elem.setValue(value.replace(regex, ''))
  })
}
```

For username, I want to modify `/[^a-z0-9_.@$#]/i` to also automatically convert any uppercase character that the user types to lowercase.

Comment: Regular Expressions are used for pattern matching - not for converting text. The idea being that you match the text using RegEx and then use whatever programming language your RegEx done with to convert the text. If you add the extra language tags to the question I'm sure someone will assist

Comment: @MacroMan - Just add the react js code. My goal is convert any uppercase characters in username to lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
/**
 * For replacing illegal characters
 */
export const replacer = (el, filter) => {
  let elem = new d(el)
  let regex =
    filter == 'username' ? /[^a-z0-9_.@$#]/i : filter == 'bio' ? /[<>]/i : null

  elem.on('keyup', e => {
    let value = e.currentTarget.value
    if (filter == 'username') {
      value = value.toLowerCase()
    }
    elem.setValue(value.replace(regex, ''))
  })
}
```

All I've done is add `.toLowerCase()` to the code. Which appears to be what you're asking for. There is no change to the regex, so really this should be tagged `javascript` I guess.

Comment: Thanks. Will test this out. I was only thinking regex.

Comment: I've made an edit that should include the wanted username check (so it doesn't run for bio)